# Where should Internet-related questions be asked?

Tags: support, closed-questions, scope

I'm not sure why [Lastpass not signing me in for certain sites](https://superuser.com/questions/110434/lastpass-not-signing-me-in-for-certain-sites) had to be closed.

Which site would you recommend for asking that type of question?  (Note: I already asked on the LastPass.com forum, but that forum is pretty much dead and nobody answers my questions.)

Comment: @John, This question is even more off-topic than the first one.  Please read the FAQ (http://superuser.com/faq).  If you have a question about this site, please visit http://meta.stackoverflow.com

Comment: In general, there is this topic on the meta site, about that kind of question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41570/super-user-questions. However, there is no answer for "internet related questions" in general.

Comment: Also, questions about the stackoverflow/superuser/serverfault sites themselves should be on the meta site, I'm voting to migrate your question there.

Comment: http://meta.StackOverflow.com/questioNs/8401/where-Can-i-ask-qUestions-that-arEnt-programming-questions

Answer (score 2):

There is now an answer to this question!  Try [the Web Apps beta](http://webapps.stackexchange.com).

Comment: ... I said, as if the OP were still around.